# Ruby namespaced class confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here's the setup:

```
# app_controller.rb
class AppController; end

# org/app_controller.rb
module Org
  class AppController < ::AppController; end
end

# org/admin/app_controller.rb
module Org
  class Admin::AppController < AppController; end
end
```

Why does `Org::Admin::AppController` inherit from `AppController`, and not `Org::AppController`, considering that the class definition is namespaced?

Comment: It _does_ inherit from `Org::AppController`, as long as `Org::Admin` already exists. If it doesn’t exist you get `uninitialized constant Org::Admin (NameError)`. (Ruby 2.1.1).

Comment: As matt comments, your code is not valid unless `Org::Admin` is defined somewhere else. So it is not reproducable as is.

Comment: I should have mentioned this is running in a Rails environment, but the error I was getting was never `uninitialized constant Org::Admin (NameError)`... it was just inheriting from the top-level `AppController`. The bug was that `AppController` defined a `before_action` and `Org::AppController` called `skip_before_action`... but it was never getting called because I didn't realize it was inheriting from the wrong class.

Comment: @matt is correct for all versions of ruby.  I updated my answer.  At the time you derived your class, `::AppController` must have been defined and `Org::AppController` must not have been.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because by the time you opened `Org::Admin::AppController`, `Org::AppController` must not have been defined, but `::AppController` must have been .  Perhaps your files are not being 'required' in the order you assumed them to be?  You might solve this by adding a `require <file containing base class>` in the file where you create your derived class.

(Minor style guideline:  Don't use `::` to refer to classes and modules that you are opening for definition.)

Edit reason:  I ran some tests and I must have been mistaken.

Comment: So, inside `module Org > module Admin`, what would `AppController` point to?

Comment: I wonder if, considering Rails and autoloading, the fact that `AppController` might already have been loaded means it won't even look for `Org::Admin::AppController` unless it also has already been loaded...

Comment: Iron Savior, in the case of nested modules, would the lookup not go up  one level at a time in search of the constant until reaching the top scope? Interesting if it instead skips to the top scope as you said, I've never had a reason to test that so I don't know.

Comment: @Andrew As it turns out, ruby does search up the surrounding module scopes.  I amended my answer after some tests with ruby 1.8, 1.9, and 2.1.